# Reactive binding of HTML with RxJS

Tags: angular, data-binding, rxjs, reactive

In the context of an Angular app, I am looking for a reactive way to bind html with rxjs observables. 
Here is a dummy example :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [checked]="check1$ | async"
      (click)="check1$.next(!check1$.getValue())"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [checked]="check2$ | async"
      (click)="check2$.next(!check2$.getValue())"
    />
    <p>status : {{ status$ | async }}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  check1$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  check2$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  status$ = combineLatest([this.check1$, this.check2$]).pipe(
    map(([c1, c2]) => {
      return `${c1}, ${c2}`;
    }),
  );
}
```

What is your opinion please ?

Many thanks for sharing best practices

Comment: It looks like what you really need is a reactive form.

Comment: something like that ?
https://blog.angulartraining.com/dynamic-filtering-with-rxjs-and-angular-forms-a-tutorial-6daa3c44076a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reactive form, thinking of

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="check1" />
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="check2" />
      <p>status : {{ check$ | async }}</p>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    check1: new FormControl(true),
    check2: new FormControl(false),
  });

  check$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    map(({ check1, check2 }) => `${check1}, ${check2}`),
  );
}
```